# Âncora não para no começo da div e link não retira sublinado azul

Tags: html, css, css-hover

Boa tarde pessoal, estou construindo um site de apenas uma página e navegação por âncoras mas estou com um problema, ao clicar no menu que redireciona pra âncora da div correspondente ao "ID" a div não para no começo da div ou seja no inicio da cor, isso aconteceu depois ue usei a class "navbar fixed" do bootstrap, ela deveria parar como na imagem abaixo esta marcado de laranja, porem ele esta parando por baixo da navbar...

Outra pergunta, por que aquela cor azul e o sublinado não sai do menu depois que é clicado? Já utilizei as 4 pseudoclasses hover,visited,active e link e nenhuma funciona com o text-decoration: none;

[image: Resultado desejado na div]

Aqui está o código do menu e das pseudoclasses:

```
#ul-menu{

 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 35px;
 word-spacing: 50px;
}

.li-menu{

 display: inline;
 font-family: 'padrao', Arial, sans-serif;

}

#testando-webfont{

 font-family: 'padrao', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.li-menu a{

 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;

}

.li-menu a:hover{

 color: #FFCBCB;
 text-decoration: none;

}

.li-menu a:active{

 text-decoration: none;

}

.li-menu a:visited{

 text-decoration: none;

}
```

Código da navbar:

```
#container-head{

 background: #483D45;
 width: 100%;
 height:90px;
}
```

Link do site: http://iracemafilha.com

Se aparecer um alerta de pishing pode ignorar, foi um problema que teve com a hospedagem, já mandei mensagem pro suporte do Google.

Comment: Crie um exemplo verificável. Use o [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ou crie um *snippet* aqui no StackOverflow.